# Show dynamic breadcrumb based on preservedRouteParameters for MvcSiteMapProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm using MvcSiteMapProvider for ASP.NET MVC5 project. I want to show a dynamic breadcrumb based on preservedRouteUrlParamters. I have multiple universities and each university has courses. I don't want to list all the university in the `mvc.sitemap`.

Instead of:

```
url: /stanford
breadcrumb: home / university

url: /stanford/course1
breadcrumb: home / university / course details
```

It should look like:

```
url: /stanford
breadcrumb: home / stanford

url: /stanford/course1
breadcrumb: home / stanford / course details ...where stanford is link to /stanford

url: /mit
breadcrumb: home / mit

url: /mit/course1
breadcrumb: home / mit / course details ...where mit is link to /mit
```

So this is the pattern:

```
url: /{university}
breadcrumb: home / {university}

url: /{university}/{course}
breadcrumb: home / {university} / course details
```

Here is the `mvc.sitemap` config I have:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="university" controller="Curriculum" action="UniversityDetails" preservedRouteParameters="university">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="course details" action="CourseDetails" preservedRouteParameters="university,course"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

This is solution I have so far but I'm not sure if it is a good way.

I use `title="{university}"` and check for the pattern `{university}`.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="{university}" controller="Curriculum" action="UniversityDetails" preservedRouteParameters="university">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="course details" action="CourseDetails" preservedRouteParameters="university,course"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I use the `SiteMapNodeModel.Url` to dynamically generate the breadcrumb.

```
public static string TitleBreadcrumb(this SiteMapNodeModel m)
{
    if (m.Title.StartsWith("{") && m.Title.EndsWith("}"))
    {
        return m.Url.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Last();
    }
    return m.Title;
}
```

I then use the above extension method in the `SiteMapNodeModel.cshtml` display template.

```
// use @Model.TitleBreadcrumb() instead of @Model.Title
<a href="@Model.Url">@Model.TitleBreadcrumb()</a>
```

Similar for `@Model.Description`.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing particularly *wrong* with your approach is that you are not encoding the value from the URL before displaying it in your HTML. This means that some malicious user could potentially inject HTML and/or JavaScript into your page by manipulating the URL.

However, the most common way to provide a dynamic title is to use the [SiteMapTitleAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Action-Filter-Attributes#sitemaptitle), which uses a value from your Model or a value in your ViewData to populate the title dynamically.

```
[SiteMapTitle("Name")]
public ViewResult UniversityDetails(string university) { 
   var model = _repository.Find(university);

   // Name is a string property of 
   // the university model object.
   return View(model); 
}

[SiteMapTitle("Name", Target = AttributeTarget.ParentNode)]
public ViewResult CourseDetails(string university) { 
   var model = _repository.Find(university);

   // Name is a string property of 
   // the university model object.
   return View(model); 
}
```